# Coupling constant in 1H NMR with phosphorus

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

I observed a doublet with peaks at 5.6336 and 5.5886 ppm with the NMR instrument running at 300 MHz, and got a $J_\ce{PH}= \pu{13.5 Hz}$. Is this correct for this molecule (ethoxycarbonylmethyl(triphenyl)phosphonium bromide)? This value is larger than the hydrogen coupling constants for the C-C bonds. Is this larger coupling constant a consequence of the phosphorous?

[image: Ethoxycarbonylmethyl(triphenyl)phosphonium Bromide]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the <sup>2</sup>J<sub>P-H</sub> coupling. You could verify this (if you had access to a NMR spectrometer) by running a <sup>1</sup>H{<sup>31</sup>P} experiment; that is, a proton with <sup>31</sup>P decoupling. This doublet would collapse back to a singlet. You would also notice some changes to the phenyl protons, as they all have some coupling to the <sup>31</sup>P also. A <sup>2</sup>J coupling of 13.5Hz is very typical for this type of <sup>1</sup>H-<sup>31</sup>P coupling.

The magnitude of <sup>1</sup>H-<sup>31</sup>P couplings varies enormously, depending on bond order, oxidation state of <sup>31</sup>P and bonding arrangement.

- <sup>1</sup>J<sub>PH</sub> of PH<sub>3</sub> = ~175Hz.
- <sup>1</sup>J<sub>PH</sub> of HP(O)(OMe)<sub>2</sub> = ~1200Hz
- <sup>2</sup>J<sub>PH</sub> P(CHx)y are typically 1-20Hz

It is sometimes observed in <sup>31</sup>P-1H (and <sup>31</sup>P-<sup>13</sup>C) that high bond order couplings are larger than lower bond order couplings (ie <sup>3</sup>J<sub>PH</sub> > <sup>2</sup>J<sub>PH</sub>)